# Rectangle pattern using arduino Mega

Tags: arduino

I am using an Arduino Mega to implement a Rectangle pattern movement of a device which mean the length and breadth should decrease each time it reaches the end edges. I have written the code but it is not working

```
//servo header
#include <Servo.h>
#include <Math.h>
Servo myservo;//servo Object

//motor pin config
int m1r = 9;
int m1f = 10;
int m2f = 12;
int m2r = 11;


//infrared counter
int ir1val=0;//pulse count from irval
int ir2val=0;//pulse count from irval

int len=1;
int bred=2;

//Different sensors used 
int temp;
int buzz = 8;

const float radpulse = 0.05;//1 pulse = 0.05 meter
double pulsecount1;//pulse counter;
double pulsecount2;//pulse counter;
int pc1;//integer 
int pc2;

void setup() {

// initialize the Motor pin as an output:
pinMode(m1f, OUTPUT);
pinMode(m1r, OUTPUT);
pinMode(m2f, OUTPUT);
pinMode(m2r, OUTPUT);
pinMode(buzz,OUTPUT);

myservo.attach(A0);//BLDC motor attachment

Serial.begin(9600);// standard serial bandwidth of all modules 
}

void loop()
{   
pulsecount1=len/radpulse;
pc1=(int)round(pulsecount1);
pulsecount2=bred/radpulse;
pc2=(int)round(pulsecount2);
pc1=3;
pc2=2;
myservo.write(30);
delay(5000);

labelL1:

if((pc2 == 0)&&(pc1 == 0))
{
 goto Stop;
}

while(pc1 > ir1val)
{
  temp=((5.0*analogRead(A3)*100)/1024);
 if(temp >60)
  {
 //   goto hibernate;
  }
/*  if((analogread(A14) <= 300 || analogread(A14) >= 400) ||        (analogread(A15) <= 300) || analogread(A15) == 400))
  {               
    goto Stop;
  }*/
  digitalWrite(m2f,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m1f,HIGH);
  //digitalWrite(m2f,HIGH);
  if(digitalRead(A2))
  {
    ir1val++;
  }
}
if(pc1 == ir1val)
{
  /*if((analogread(A14) <= 300 || analogread(A14) >= 400) || (analogread(A15) <= 300) || analogread(A15) == 400))
    {               
     goto Stop;
    }*/
    pc1--;
    ir1val=0;
    digitalWrite(m1f, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(m2f,LOW);
    delay(5000);
    goto labelB1;
}
labelB1:
while(pc2 != ir1val)
{
  temp=((5.0*analogRead(A3)*100)/1024);
  if(temp >60)
  {
 //   goto label2;
  }
/*  if((analogread(A14) <= 300 || analogread(A14) >= 400) || (analogread(A15) <= 300) || analogread(A15) == 400))
  {              
    goto Stop;
  }*/
  digitalWrite(m1f,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m2f,HIGH);
  if(digitalRead(A2))
  {
    ir2val++;
  }
}
if(pc2 == ir2val)
{
  /*  if((analogread(A14) <= 300 || analogread(A14) >= 400) || (analogread(A15) <= 300) || analogread(A15) == 400))
  {               
    goto Stop;
  }*/
  pc2=pc2--;
  ir2val=0;
  digitalWrite(m1f, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(m2f,LOW);
  delay(5000);
  goto labelL1;
}
Stop:
  myservo.write(0);// stop servo
 digitalWrite(m1f,LOW);// stop motor
 digitalWrite(m2f,LOW);//stop motor
  digitalWrite(buzz,HIGH);//Buzzer
  delay(5000);
goto Stop;

/*
hibernate:
temp=((5.0*analogRead(A2)*100)/1024);
  if(temp >40)
  {
    delay(1000);
    goto hibernate;
  }
*/}
```

Comment: please highlight the area of problem instead of posting all of the codes.

Comment: What exactly does it do, and in what way is it different than what you want? The more work you do in explaining your problem, the less work others will have to do in order to help you. Aside from this being the polite way to ask, it is also the most efficient i.e. you will get more and better answers.